# Copy Animator Component to other GameObjects

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I would like to copy a Explosion Animation of my gameObject.
I tried copying the component but it seems it won't play the explosion animation to my new gameObject. How am I supposed to reuse my explosion animation to all of my gameObjects?

Answer (score 1):

the animation file is connected to gameobjects by name, meaning that if you want to add an explosion to allot of gameobjects you need them to have the same name.
but that is very bad practice, so it is better that your animator will be on a parent, every parent will have a child with the same name (lets call it ExplosionObject), and the animation will be connected to the child instead of the parent.

Also, if the exploding game objects are all the same it is better to just make a prefab of them, the prefab will have the animator on it, and you would just have to instantiate it by minimal code.
good luck, if you have other questions regarding this I will be glad to help